# HTML page not getting value from data base using php script

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am getting data from mysql data base using php script problem is that in table there is data but when i fetch returen NO only

it shows following error

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/emrapp/surveyDescription.php on line 73
```

[]

HTML CODE

```
  <html<body>
   <INPUT TYPE = "Text" VALUE ="user_id" NAME = "user_id"> This form allows you to connect to the server.<br>
   <form action="surveyDescription.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>

   Type (or select) Filename: 
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </html>
```

PHP CODE

```
   <?php 
   $host = "********"; 
   $user = "********"; 
   $pass = "********"; 
   $database = "****"; 

   $linkID = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host."); 
   mysql_select_db($database, $linkID) or die("Could not find database."); 

  if (!function_exists('json_encode'))
  {
   function json_encode($a=false)
  {
  if (is_null($a)) return 'null';
  if ($a === false) return 'false';
  if ($a === true) return 'true';
  if (is_scalar($a))
   {
    if (is_float($a))
    {
    // Always use "." for floats.
    return floatval(str_replace(",", ".", strval($a)));
    }

    if (is_string($a))
    {
    static $jsonReplaces = array(array("\\", "/", "\n", "\t", "\r", "\b", "\f", '"'), array('\\\\', '\\/', '\\n', '\\t', '\\r', '\\b', '\\f', '\"'));
    return '"' . str_replace($jsonReplaces[0], $jsonReplaces[1], $a) . '"';
    }
    else
    return $a;
    }
    $isList = true;
    for ($i = 0, reset($a); $i < count($a); $i++, next($a))
    {
    if (key($a) !== $i)
    {
     $isList = false;
     break;
     }
     }
     $result = array();
     if ($isList)
     {
     foreach ($a as $v) $result[] = json_encode($v);
     return '[' . join(',', $result) . ']';
     }
     else
     {
     foreach ($a as $k => $v) $result[] = json_encode($k).':'.json_encode($v);
     return '{' . join(',', $result) . '}';
     }
     }
     }



   $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT s.*, u.user_id FROM survey_master AS s 
   JOIN user_profile AS u on u.user_id = s.user_id where s.user_id=$user_id");

   $rows = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
 $rows[] = $row;
 }
echo json_encode($rows);

  ?>
```

Comment: Oh boy. Props to whoever has the time to explain everything wrong with this.

Comment: there's an error in your query.

Comment: can you expalin the error and how to remove that error

Comment: Dude, remove your host, username, and pass...Put in some dummy values there or remove that section completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT s.*, u.user_id FROM survey_master AS s 
JOIN user_profile AS u on u.user_id = s.user_id where s.user_id=$user_id");
```

May be $user_id don't have any value.please check that.

Comment: i am echo $used_id but does not show anything i am entering value in textbox

Comment: your user_id input box is out side form that's why put it into the form and one more thing user_id have int value as i understand your code.

Comment: if it is var char then use this $query = mysql_query("SELECT s.*, u.user_id FROM survey_master AS s 
JOIN user_profile AS u on u.user_id = s.user_id where s.user_id='".$user_id."' "); And also put input box under form tag.

Comment: i think problem is in querry where we use where clause becuase now user_id is also showing in echo

Comment: Ajay but when i call this same script from iphone app it is not working for me for testing i used html page

Comment: i don't have any idea about iphone app but according to my knowledge query works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Put `<input>` inside your `form` tag

```
<body>

   <form action="surveyDescription.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>
   <INPUT TYPE = "Text" VALUE ="user_id" NAME = "user_id"> This form allows you
    to connect to the server.<br>
   Type (or select) Filename: 
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

More syntax errors:

`<html>` tag is missing ">" and you didn't close the `<body>` tag at the end